# How do I build a generic authentication Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building a Web API app, to primarily service a pure HTML + Angular UI app, but also to any authorized party. Now I would like primarily the Web API, but also the UI, to use an 'injected/configured' authentication service. I would like to write the least code and really get the most out of what ASP.NET and Identity can give me on this.

What are the established and or accepted models and practices for achieving this?

Granted, the app owner can't use any auth service, it must comply with an archetype, maybe implement an interface, or consume certain custom services, etc. but I'd like my app to be able top easily switch between most common scenarios, whatever those are right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, I would like to say that Security is hard.

**Second thing**, The MVC security is typically *cookie based*. The cookie is either obtained via a local login page, or by using an external identity provider (SSO). If it's obtained from a central SSO provider, then you need to look into protocols such as *WS-Federation*, *OpenID Connect* or you can use the *social media providers* various implementations.

**Third thing**, Web API security (which would be how you secure from your client-side angular code) would be *token based*. The token would be obtained via *OAuth*. This means you need an *OAuth authorization server*. This can be hosted locally (as you would with your local login page for cookie based authentication), or it can be hosted centrally (as you would for an external SSO login provider).

With the evolution of front-end frameworks and the huge change on how we build web applications nowadays the preferred approach to authenticate users is to use signed token as this token sent to the server with each request. Some of the benefits for using this approach are:

- Scalability of Servers
- Loosely Coupling
- Mobile Friendly

A good tutorial and demonstration is available in 
[Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

Also, Please take a look at [IdentityServer3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3) which:

> is a framework and a hostable component that allows implementing
>   single sign-on and access control for modern web applications and APIs
>   using protocols like OpenID Connect and OAuth2. It supports a wide
>   range of clients like mobile, web, SPAs and desktop applications and
>   is extensible to allow integration in new and existing architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that those are just the most basic settings. I would highly recommend starting with a `File > New Project` which already have identity configured.

Identity is more complex to implement in all applications because you need all levels of the application to actually make it work (visual, business logic, database, etc.)

If you need a complete solution, I would take a look at [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/) and its [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/).

---

In your `Startup.cs/ConfigureServices` ensure to have the following section:

```cs
// Configure our application database context to be Entity Framework backed by SQL Server
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("Database:Connection")));

// Specify the configuration of our Application database context
services.Configure(options =>
{
    options.DefaultUsername = Configuration.Get("DefaultUser:Username");
    options.DefaultPassword = Configuration.Get("DefaultUSer:Password");
});

// Configure ASP.NET Identity to use our Identity-based application context
services.AddIdentity()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Which will require something like this in your `config.json` :

```
{
  "Mode": "Development",
  "Database": {
    "Connection": "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "DefaultUser": {
    "Username": "myUsername",
    "Password": "MyP@ssword!"
  }
}
```

Then in your `Startup.cs/Configure` we actually have to use the service itself:

```cs
app.UseIdentity();
```

The only thing missing are the `AuthorizeAttribute` on your controllers.